# echo -en "\033]0;$(pwd) \a" Illegal variable name

Tags: linux, terminal

I'm trying to show the directory name without a path to the CentOS terminal tab in CShell.

I found an example from google but it make an error `Illegal variable name`

```
echo -en "\033]0;$(pwd) \a"
```

How I can show the directory name without a path to linux terminal tab?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the stuff in your command.

```
echo -e "$(pwd)"
```

You can even leave off the `-n`. This works in BASH shell. I don't have CSH installed on my RHEL system.
\033]0; just adds color to the prompt. For example:

```
echo -e "\e[1m$(pwd)\e[0m"
```

This will print your current directory in **bold**.

Comment: echo -e "$(pwd)" it does not work. same error as Illegal variable name. Probably it only works in BASH?

Comment: Yeah it may only work in BASH. It also works in KSH. Just switch shells and test it.  I have not used CSH in a long time. I switched to the BASH / VI combination when I became a sys admin, because most system will have both installed.

Comment: The old method for ```$( )``` was   \` \` . So for example \`pwd\`. Not ' but \`. This is the same key as ~. Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: set var = `pwd` and echo "\033]0;$var\a"  this is work but when I change the directory, the tab title does not changed. what am I supposed to do that?

Comment: `\033]0;` is _not_ color, it's setting the terminal title.